# wget calling another page before calling what I actually called

Tags: wget, malware

I'm using a simple wget call to download an xml file. The output log shows another page that I totally did not call is being called first. Is it a virus or malware on my server? Why am I seeing http://lyrics.url.com/ when I never called it? I see "301 Moved Permanently", but why?

Here is some sample...

Call:

```
sudo wget --output-document=/home/main/nfl_liveupdate_scorestrip_ss.xml URL "https://nfl.com/liveupdate/scorestrip/ss.xml"
```

Output log:

```
--2016-07-10 20:12:42--  http://url/
Resolving url (url)... 52.0.146.161, 52.200.98.122
Connecting to url (url)|52.0.146.161|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 301 Moved Permanently
Location: http://lyrics.url.com/ [following]
0 redirections exceeded.
--2016-07-10 20:12:42--  https://nfl.com/liveupdate/scorestrip/ss.xml
Resolving nfl.com (nfl.com)... 23.63.181.201
Connecting to nfl.com (nfl.com)|23.63.181.201|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 301 Moved Permanently
Location: https://www.nfl.com/liveupdate/scorestrip/ss.xml [following]
```

Comment: Doing `dig +short nfl.com` shows their IP address as 172.230.194.189 ... so something seems off.

Comment: @OrganicMarble NFL.com is being hosted on a distributed network (Akamai), that's why each query and each different server returns different IPs. Try refreshing [this page](https://toolbox.googleapps.com/apps/dig/#A/nfl.com@8.8.8.8) a few times, and try different DNS servers—you'll see different IPs every time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `wget` command contains the argument "`URL`" after `--output-document=...` and before the actual URL that you want.  I don't know what you expect that to do, but what it's actually doing is telling `wget` to fetch the page at the URL "`URL`", which `wget` interprets as "`http://url.com`", which redirects to `http://lyrics.url.com/`, and thus the behavior you're seeing here happens.  Get rid of the "`URL`" argument.

Comment: Beautiful answer! Have my +1

Comment: That was it! Thanks much, not sure why I struggled so much and did not notice. Much appreciated.

Answer (score -2):

This might be confusing, but it's actually "okay". The domain "nfl.com" returns a different IP address than "www.nfl.com" does, and the content delivery network is configured to redirect you to the correct address. If you use "http://www.nfl.com/liveupdate/scorestrip/ss.xml" (notice the "www"!) to begin with, there will be no redirect.

Comment: I believe the OP is concerned about http://lyrics.url.com appearing in the output, not about the addition of `www.` to their desired URL.